# Android DataBinding new button setOnClickListener

Tags: android, kotlin, button, binding, onclicklistener

I need to use the Android Camera.
Therefore I am using following Template: https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/main/Camera2SlowMotion

I added a Butten to the fragment_camera.xml
https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/main/Camera2SlowMotion/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_camera.xml

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/change_focus_button"
    android:layout_width="115dp"
    android:layout_height="81dp"
    android:text="@string/focusButtonText"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="13dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="473dp" />
```

In the CameraFragment.kt I now want to call a function when the button is clicked.
In my understanding I therefore need to create a setOnClickListener.

https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/main/Camera2SlowMotion/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2/slowmo/fragments/CameraFragment.kt

I thought about adding following line in Line 309. that would call a function i then create. But the "." after fragmentCameraBinding.changeFocusButton is always red and won't go away.

```
fragmentCameraBinding.changeFocusButton.setOnClickListener { chnageFocuslen() }
```

What do I need to change / where do I need to add the OnClickListener?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to download the sample because I couldn't see what the issue was from the snippets in your post.

The issue is that `CameraFragment` has **two** layout files, one in the default folder `layout`, and one in `layout-land` for landscape orientation. So you need to add your `change_focus_button` XML to both layout files to make it not `nullable` when you access it via `fragmentCameraBinding` in `CameraFragment`.

Comment: Glad it helped. If you don't mind, can you mark it correct?